# Install differences / considerations between 75' water well and 300' deep water well

Tags: well, well-pump

I'm wondering what the practical differences are when installing a water system in a 300' deep well vs a 75' deep well.  The info I've found for "deep water wells" mostly refers to wells only 100' or so.  I have a 75' deep well with a 220v single-phase submersible pump (1 or 3/4 HP), 1" schedule 80 pvc pipe w/ check valve, and pitless adapter on the casing; so I'm somewhat familiar with these installations.

My son is looking at a possible 300' well.  What sort of allowances does one have to make for the long electrical run to the pump?  Should the pipe be larger diameter?  Is schedule 80 pvc still ok for the pipe?  For a 6gpm well, what size pump would be required?

Any pointers to resources would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have made the modern (and sensible/efficient) choice of a submersible pump, it's mostly just choosing the right one for the well you have. You generally won't use the same pump for a 75 foot well and a 300 foot well. When shopping you see what's available that includes 6GPM in the 300 foot depth box if that's what you are looking for.

I suppose you can use PVC-80 sticks - I personally have a pump hanging on 200PSI black polyethylene, 300 feet down (289 feet of pipe in the well, due to where the pitless is on the casing, and how long the pump is.)

Wire just needs to meet the requirements of your pump, and there are detailed charts in the pump manual. Total distance matters, not just the down-hole portion of it. IIRC, 2-wire (+ ground) allowed smaller wire than 3-wire (+ground) for my pump. I use 2-wire for the same reason I don't use a deep well jet - the reliability of the electric parts has come such a long way that there's really no need to keep them on the surface, and the 2-wire submersible is more efficient.

If you have 3-phase available and a need for that much pump that's a different ball of wax, but 300 feet and 6 GPM should not require that.

Pipe size  is a function of total pipe length and flow rate .vs. friction head and velocity in the pipe all balanced against incremental cost. For 6 GPM 1 inch 400 feet of (plastic) pipe (if its 100 feet or less from the well to the house) is under [5 PSI friction head at 6 GPM](http://irrigation.wsu.edu/Content/Calculators/General/Pipeline-Pressure-Loss.php) at a velocity of [2.45 ft per second](http://irrigation.wsu.edu/Content/Calculators/General/Pipe-Velocity.php). Which makes the increased cost of 1-1/4" pipe a dubious place to put money.